# Difference between @Binding var a: Int and Binding<Int> in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a UIPageViewController that's wrapped up into a SwiftUI view. The view is instantiated with a `@Binding` value:

```
PageView([Text("Hello")], currentPage: $page)
```

I have some internal state that I'd like to change based on the incoming `@Binding` variable.

```
    @State var currentPageIndex: Int
    @State var goRight: Bool?
    
    public var currentPage: Binding<Int> {
        Binding(
            get: {
                return self.currentPageIndex
        },
            set: {
                self.goRight = ((self.currentPageIndex - $0) > 0)
                self.currentPageIndex = $0
        }
        )
    }
```

When I try to set the UIPageViewController based on this index,

```
pageViewController.setViewControllers([controllers[currentPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true)
```

this line fails with the error `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int>' to expected argument type 'Int'`

Yet when I simply use a `@Binding` value without doing anything to it,

```
@Binding var currentPage: Int
```

everything compiles just fine. I understand the core of this issue to be, there's some sort of difference between `@Binding var blah: Int` and `var blah: Binding<Int>` Why is this the case? Why is there something else I have to do to access the underlying value of a type `Binding<Int>`? I understand these things to be two different ways of saying the same thing. Or are they not equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
@Binding var blah: Int
```

`blah` is an `Int` and the `@Binding` is a property wrapper that projects a value via `$blah`, which is a type of `Binding<Int>`. So, they are not the same.

Likewise, `@State` property wrapper projects a `Binding`. So, you actually don't need to create a computed property, like you did with `public var currentPage: Binding<Int>`. You can just do:

```
self.$currentPageIndex
```

But, if you need to access the underlying value from `Binding<T>`, you can use the `.wrappedValue` property

Comment: In my case I wanted just the .wrappedValue and nothing else...

Answer (score 4):

```swift
@Binding var blah: Int
```

becomes

```swift
var _blah: Binding<Int>
var blah: Int {
    get {
        _blah.wrappedValue
    }
    set {
        _blah.wrappedValue = newValue
    }
}
```

---

This means that if you have a `@Binding var foo: Int` and `var bar: Binding<Int>`, here's how you would do equivalent things:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    //assume these are correctly initialized
    @Binding var foo: Int
    var bar: Binding<Int>

    var body: some View {
        //some body
    }

    func example() {
        // these are equivalent
        foo == bar.wrappedValue
        _foo == bar
    }
}
```